# GIT: no arrow / marker in conflict file, database.yml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git

I've tried `git push` to a hosting service (not heroku). The following error is displayed on the hosting service screen.

```
U   config/database.yml
Pull is not possible because you have unmerged files.
Please, fix them up in the work tree, and then use 'git add/rm <file>'
as appropriate to mark resolution, or use 'git commit -a'.
```

Although I was told to edit the conflicted file like followings, the file which is saved on local machine is not showing any arrow/marker.

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
# aaaa
=======
# bbbb
>>>>>>> d67046xxxxxxxxx
```

I did the followings but no arrow/marker displayed.

```
git add .
git commit -m "xxx"
git push xxx master
```

No error is displayed as below after `git push`.

```
c:\xxx\rails\app>git push foo master
Counting objects: 7, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
Writing objects: 100% (4/4), 454 bytes, done.
Total 4 (delta 3), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote:
To ssh://xxx@xxx.xxx:2222/xxx/xxx.git
   8199bb1..5d4a490  master -> master
```

How do I display arrow/marker or resolve conflict?

Comment: Is it saved and committed?

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply. I saved and commited the file as I update my question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are in terminal. do:

```
$ git status
```

This will display the branch, untracked files, changes and other differences

```
$ git add .
```

git add will included all changed files into commit

```
$ git commit -m "NAME YOUR COMMIT"
```

*"Stores the current contents of the index in a new “commit.” This commit contains the changes made and a message created by the user."*

```
$ git push origin master
```

*"Push and merge changes from a branch to a remote & branch."* I assume that you are in branch master.

I would encourage you to learn more about GIT, good resources:

1. Simple Guide - http://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/
2. Free eBook from git-tower - http://www.git-tower.com/learn/ebook/command-line/introduction
3. ProGit Free Book - http://git-scm.com/book
4. Getting Started with GIT - http://git-scm.com/book/en/Getting-Started Great article about GIT
5. Workflows - https://www.atlassian.com/git/workflows#!workflow-gitflow

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply and explanation. Although I did `git add .`, `git commit -m "xxx"` and then `git push origin master`, I was told it was conflicted.

Comment: If you do ```git status``` do you get following(or similar) response: ```# On branch master nothing to commit (working directory clean)```

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @Tom Hert. Yes, `# On branch master nothing to commit, working directory clean` is displayed. I'm newbie for GIT, so I will learn more about GIT as you advised. But it would be appreciated if you could give me some advise.

Comment: And when you hit the ```git push origin master``` you got which error?

Comment: No error message is appeared in command line as I updated my question above (foo is my hosting server). But the error as I wrote at the beginning of my question was appeared on the hosting server side and I couldn't deploy my application.

Comment: Resolving GIT conflicts is not trivial as it might seen. Basically, you have to decide, which version is correct and resolve it manually. I would recommend to read following https://help.github.com/articles/resolving-a-merge-conflict-from-the-command-line/ and use Google to obtain more information about resolving GIT conflicts

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @Tom Hert. I will read the resources you linked to obtain more information.